# Como acceder a atributo dentro de objeto dentro de colección

Tags: java

tengo un problema a la hora de encontrar un objeto libro a través de un atributo(isbn)en una colección, tengo el atributo para comparar pero no consigo acceder al mismo atributo de los objetos de mi colección, no añado mas implementación para simplificar la duda lo máximo posible, me lanza este error( The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList de libros )porfa ¿como podría hacer la conversión de tipo para tener la expresión de if() correcta?:

```
    ArrayList<Libro> coleccion1 = new ArrayList<Libro>();
    Libro libro = new Libro();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        libro.crearLibro();
        coleccion1.add(libro);
        
    }
        socketAlCliente = socketServidor.accept();
        System.out.println("Petición número: "+ peticiones);
        entrada = new InputStreamReader(socketAlCliente.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(entrada);
    
String librorecibido = bf.readLine();
int isbnrecibido = Integer.parseInt(librorecibido);
                for (int i = 0; i < coleccion1.size(); i++) {
                    if(isbnrecibido == coleccion1[i].getisbn) {
                        
                }
```

Comment: Trata de no resumir mucho tu consulta, ¿Qué valores tienen ``librorecibido``, ``coleccion1``? ¿Cómo están declarados?, revisa [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Dónde te falla exactamente? Puedes poner el resto que has implementado? Necesitamos más información

Comment: el getisbn puedes mostrar de qué tipo es?

Comment: el getisbn es el método getter del atributo isbn de la clase Libro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad `coleccion1` es un `ArrayList` por lo tanto para acceder a sus elementos usa el método `get()` y el indice del elemento, suponiendo que tu objeto `Libro` tiene un "getter" llamado `getisbn()` , puedes obtener el valor de esta forma:

```
coleccion1.get(indice).getisbn()
```

Esto sería aplicandolo a tu código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < coleccion1.size(); i++) {
      //if(isbnrecibido == coleccion1[i].getisbn) {
      if(isbnrecibido == coleccion1.get(i).getisbn()) {

      //Es igual!                

     }
}
```